# Concurrency Kit hash table and multiple writers

Tags: concurrency, hashtable

In Concurrency Kit documentation I see SPMC in `get` and `put` operations:

```
ck_ht_get_spmc()
ck_ht_put_spmc()
```

Does it means I can't use this hash table for multiple writers and I will have race conditions?

Currently I use mutex with `put` operation to make it work like single writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, from the documentation for [`ck_ht_init`](http://concurrencykit.org/doc/ck_ht_init.html):

> The hash table is safe to access by multiple readers in the presence of      one concurrent writer. Behavior is undefined in the presence of concurrent writers.